# RPS JFrame Collection (RPS101 not working!)

Tags: java, jframe

I'm currently working on an RPS Game, based on David Lovelace's variants [here](http://www.umop.com/rps.htm). It's based in a JFrame application, with tabs for each of the seven variants (including RPSLS). A GitHub link can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/AidanPTD/c11e5a500fafefc06982c2dd7646a92e).

My issue: Every "game" works perfectly except RPS101 - some outcomes match up with each other, and others don't. I'm thinking that it's either my decideOutcome function and how it's finding the choices and the outcomes FOR those choices, or it's the order that the outcomes are in for the double array. Anyone mind helping me out on this one?

Other notes:

- The output prints in the console of the compiler that you're using (or command line) - I'm currently using IntelliJ 2017.3.
- The "result" JLabel is supposed to show the outcome of the two choices (user's and CPU's), but this program is still in the testing stage.

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: Please read [ask] and when you understand it, change your question accordingly.

Comment: @JorgeCampos, is this better (see updated post)? Sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow (and Stack in general), so thanks for pointing that out for me.

Comment: No it didn't. Please read carefully the section "Help others reproduce the problem" from the provided link. And welcome to Stack Overflow